# Should I need to put an article before proper noun- in the following case?

Tags: definite-article, proper-nouns

Normally I know that it's incorrect to put an article before proper nouns but in this case I doubt whether I need to put an article before the proper noun.

The context is:

> "The main difference is that (**the**?) Atlas has no body, unlike the rest of vertebrae"

Comment: What is "Atlas" in this context? is this a person, a political party, a species?

Comment: Also, "unlike the rest ***of*** vertebrae".

Comment: @Kreiri, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(anatomy)  (it's the top cervical vertebra).

Comment: Where did the sentence come from?  Did you write that?  If you did, yes, you need the definite article.  And the name of the vertebra is not written with the capital 'a'.  It's "the atlas", not "the Atlas".

Comment: . . .and 'rest of *the* vertebrae' too.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a proper noun here. It should be treated as a common noun,countable, so you are quite right when you use articles. The definition can be easily found Oxforddictionaries.com.